# firebase auth state is changed without reason on mobile only

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I have a auth.service and subscribe to the authState to check if the current user is logged in already.

```
constructor(
    private firebaseAuth: AngularFireAuth,
  ) {
    this.firebaseAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
      this.authState = user;
      this.isLoading$.next(false);
    });
```

the isLoading$ is only there for the guard to wait until the state is loaded.

The problem I have is, on my android the authState returns allways null. And if I login the authState is set but after 1-2seconds the state is already changed to null again and I have no idea why. It's no problem on desktop connections, i tested with 3 computers and chrome and firefox, the state is set and stays there and a refresh also brings back the state.

<s>and even if when the state is back to null, I'm able interact with the database, its only the guard throwing my back to the login if a route change happens.</s>
=> wrong database rule!

so it seems that firebase logs my user out but I have not called logout

why does the authState changes back to null without logout?

where is the full code:
https://github.com/muehan/mue-shoplist

Comment: It could be because the service does not continue running because it not high enough in the hierarchy. However, from what you provided, there is no way to tell that this is the answer so please provide more when you can because your current code should work.

Comment: but why does it only happen on the phone? I add more code

Comment: if the service stops running would it not result in unsubscribe and not in a null value gets passed in?

Comment: Ok, after looking over your code, does `authService.loading$` return `false` as it should?

Comment: yes it does. and it only has an impact on the guard. i get redirected to the list as it should and as long as I don't change the route i'm in the list component and can add and remove stuff

Comment: Where in your program is the subscription returning null? Also, no, the service would not result in an "unsubscribe" that can be tracked. I still think it is probably recreating the service and therefore returning null because the original service is not the service you are tacking -  the service is instead being recreated by android and returning its initial value of null.

Comment: On de Desktop and also on the Phone from my wife it's not return null. and the idea behind that subscription is that a new service loads the authState which was created by another/older service instance. it's the solution from the docs: https://angularfirebase.com/snippets/angularfire2-version-4-authentication-service/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169411/discussion-between-drei-and-andre).